# Error on calling a rosservice

Tags: rosservice, hector-quadrotor, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Im trying to enable `hector_quadrotor` motors' on throught  code:

```
  int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   ros::init(argc, argv, ROS_PACKAGE_NAME);

   ros::NodeHandle nh;

  ros::ServiceClient enable_motors = nh.serviceClient<hector_uav_msgs::EnableMotors>("enable_motors");

  hector_uav_msgs::EnableMotors motors;
  motors.request.enable = true;

  if (enable_motors.call(motors)){
    ROS_INFO("Motors on");
  }
  else{
   ROS_INFO("Motors off");   
 }
```

However, calling the service always fails (returns 0) and results on the else statement.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284293/error-on-calling-a-rosservice/) by [bxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/30323/bxl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2018-03-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have to wait for service to become available:

`enable_motors.waitForExistence()`

---

Originally posted by [bxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/30323/bxl/) with karma: 56 on 2018-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0